# React.js, prefer controlled input over jquery?

Tags: jquery, requirejs

We've been using controlled input components.

For a form, this means we have a local react state where we store the controlled input values.

Now looking back, I think it's so much easier to use jquery to access form field's value on time of submit.

Although I haven't seen example code to do that. Is there any downside of doing jquery way?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [Redux Forms](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/), a popular library to manage your state in forms.
It will manage all the intricacies and exposes to you components which are easy to use.